# How can I recreate my skyrim save file?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, after reinstalling Skyrim and stuff my save file has gotten somewhat corrupted causing random crashes. So, I was thinking, is there a way to export and import just the following things:

- Character levels & perks
- Character inventory
- Completed quests

But discard

- Stored items
- General state of the world (e.g. characters that got killed by a dragon would revive)
- Running scripts
- Quest stages (though maybe this could be safely kept as well, dunno?)
- Anything else (houses you own, etc. etc.)

I get that this might result in some weird and possibly even conflicting situations (a character that was supposed to be killed in a quest being alive despite the quest being marked completed or something), but it seems quite useful and would definitely be worth it if it solves my issues and on top of that it would be a way to safely uninstall most mods. I think I could get quite far using the console and some scripting interface by hand, but that would take more programming time then I can invest right now and somebody must have made something along these lines already (as corrupt save files due to mods are far from rare).

Comment: its all doable via console commands, but you have to do each individually so its going to be quite the hassle

Comment: I know of tools for cleaning up savegames, which do some of the above, but I have no experience of using them. [Save Cleaner](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/31724/?) resets items and cells, resetting NPCs who had an unfortunate accident in the process. Another major issue are orphaned scripts, which [Script Cleaner](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/52363/?) might take care of. I am not affiliated with any of these.

Comment: @MRLemon That's definitely an alternative approach, going to try it out now and if you make it an answer I will definitely at the very least upvote it.

Comment: How did you conclude that it is your save file causing crashes?

Comment: @Nelson It started after reinstalling my OS and the log files reference missing objects and those references aren't mod specific (didn't have any mods installed back then).

Comment: @MrLemon Nope, didn't do the trick... so odd, I just can't wrap my head around what could be causing it, graphic quality influences the frequency of the crashes and on one of my first saves it doesn't happen...

Comment: Were you using mods ?

Comment: @Vinz243 Nope, though I did found out in the meantime that actually it does happen even on earlier saves/clean saves... just less often...

Answer (score 1):

Save files are stored as a compressed order of bits, in a way that often makes it intentionally difficult for any outside influence to alter it.

What you will be looking for is a Save Trainer, or some other application specifically designed to read a Skyrim save and alter it.

If your able to at least see your progress in the areas you wish to 'port over', a save trainer will allow you to just alter a new save to reflect the same values. If your having trouble recovering partials of your save, you can at least go off memory.